# What is the best way to know the latest file in s3 bucket?

Tags: amazon-s3, amazon-sqs, amazon-sns

I have a process which is uploading files to S3. The rate at which these are files are pumped to S3 is not constant. Another process needs to look into the latest files uploaded in this bucket and update, say watermark. Now we need the best-effort strategy to make this "latest file" available information as soon as possible.

S3 has event notification integration with SNS/SQS. Since I don't need a fan-out, I thought I could simply do a S3 -> SQS integration. But on digging deep into SQS, I see that though there are no limits on the number of SQS queues you can have per account (I would need quite a lot of queues if I were to assign SQS per partition in S3), there is a limit on max number of messages you can receive per call - 10

Though I can setup SQS per partition, i.e Q1 for root/child1, Q2 for root/child2, etc. The number of files getting pumped into these child folder itself could be massive. In that case, instead of trying to drain everything in the queue - JUST to get the latest file in the child directory, is there any other mechanism I could apply?

Note I am not 100% done with my POC and I certainly don't have the metrics - but given that long-polling (the more you wait, the more delay in getting out the latest file information. so short poll is probably what I should be using - but then there is a possibility that it does not send the request to all SQS servers so I would need multiple calls to get the latest event out from SQS. Need to find a balance there), 10 per call limit, etc, I just doubt if I am using the right tool for the problem here. Am I missing something? or am I terribly wrong about SQS?

I am yet to experiment SNS - does it do rate limiting for events? "If there are 10000 events per minute I will only send you the latest one" sort of?

Please let me know what is the best way to get the latest file uploaded in S3 when the rate of files uploaded is high.

Comment: What about saving the upload_at time info into DynamoDB? This way you can get the latest file in real-time.

Comment: Not an option since Kafka connect's S3 connector is used

Comment: Actually we had only one component do everything from conversion, s3 upload and watermark update but that's putting a lot of load on one instance. With scaling out, there isn't one component which has eagle eye on all data to update watermark. So we had to do this watermark aggregation by reading what's latest in all S3 partitions. Since we are using Kafka connect for conversion and S3 sink, publishing latest time isn't easy as well - unless I use Kafka api and trace the committed offset and read the events from topic itself. But that's crude and messy.